# Rails external css framework not loading in some browsers

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, https, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails 4 application where I am using purecss framework for grids and a few other items. (http://purecss.io). I have quite a bit of custom css as well.

In production, my css is working, except the purecss parts, and only in firefox and chrome. Safari works ok and in dev, all browsers work ok.

Not sure how to troubleshoot, production logs don't seem to show any errors.
I've tried precompiling assets again.

head section of layouts/application.html.erb

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.3.0/pure-min.css"> 

<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

application.css.scss

```
*
 *= require_self
 */

@import "reset.css.scss"; 
@import "main.css.scss";
@import "signin.css.scss";
@import "flash.css.scss";
@import "gmaps4rails.css";
@import "library.css.scss";
@import "mobile.css.scss";
@import "charges.css.scss";
@import "flash.css.scss";
@import "pages.css.scss";
```

**EDIT**

A bit more digging shows I left out some important items.

The site is https, it's the first time I've ever used ssl so it kind of slipped my mind.
Chrome console is showing

```
[blocked] The page at ####### ran insecure content from http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.3.0/pure-min.css.

[blocked] The page at ####### ran insecure content from http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200,300,400,600,700,300italic.
```

So I guess the different browsers had different security settings. STill not sure how to fix. I could download the purecss library and host myself, but that can't be the best fix, and how do I handle the google font ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the `stylesheet_link_tag` and just pass it the URL of the CSS you're trying to load...

`stylesheet_link_tag "http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.3.0/pure-min.css"`

See [the stylesheet_link_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-stylesheet_link_tag) API docs for more info.  I'm not 100% sure this will solve your problem, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: made that change but no luck, still same issue.

Comment: Thanks, Chrome showed some insecure error message, I edited my question above.

Comment: Sounds like you're using `https` on your page and trying to access the fonts css using `http`...  Is this correct?  If so, change the URL to access the fonts to `https://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.3.0/pure-min.css`

Comment: I dropped http from the google font link and that worked. But it won't work for the purecss library. They don't offer it over ssl. Going to have to host that myself. So going to close the question, and accept the answer, thanks